# Spring @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED) does not roll out outer transaction when inner transaction throws an exception

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have used below code from some tutorial:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        OuterBean testBean = (OuterBean) ctx.getBean("outerBeanImpl");

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("johndoe");
        user.setName("John Doe");
        try{
            testBean.testRequired(user);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("in main class");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

OuterBeanImpl class

```
@Service
public class OuterBeanImpl implements OuterBean {

    @Autowired
    private TestDAO testDAO;

    @Autowired
    private InnerBean innerBean;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void testRequired(User user) {
        testDAO.insertUser(user);
        try{
            innerBean.testRequired();
        } catch(RuntimeException e){
            System.out.println("OuterBeanImpl class");
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void testRequiresNew(User user) {
        testDAO.insertUser(user);
        try{
            innerBean.testRequiresNew();
        } catch(Exception e){
            // handle exception
        }
    }

}

@Service
public class InnerBeanImpl implements InnerBean {

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void testRequired() {
        System.out.println("Rollback this required transaction!");
        throw new RuntimeException("Rollback this required transaction!");
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void testRequiresNew() {
        System.out.println("Rollback this new transaction!");
        throw new RuntimeException("Rollback this new transaction!");
    }
}
```

My spring configuration is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.dao.impl" />
    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.test.impl" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
       <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
             <prop 
             key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
          </props>
       </property>
       <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.model" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As the methods testRequired() in both beans are marked as required, as the inner transaction throws an exception the outer transaction must roll out the transaction. But this is not happening in here. 
Can anyone suggest as what I am doing wrong?

THanks,

Comment: which transactionManager are you using?

Comment: @Massimo: <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
  p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
 </bean>

Comment: @Massimo: FYI, I am referring the following tutorial:   http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-propagation-tutorial

Comment: Have you tried using a JtaTransactionManager? like what is being expressed here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

I'm guessing that HibernateTM doesn't support this kind of propagations tricks, but I could be mistaken

Comment: Did you also specify   <tx:annotation-driven /> ?

Comment: @AndreasAumayr : Yes, I have edited my question with my spring configuration for your reference.

Comment: Oh, one more thing.
In the main you are calling testBean.testRequired(user) which is not being proxyed, hence I think it's not getting the transactional's annotation.

Care to try and inject it?

Comment: @Massimo: how to try that?

Comment: I guess you can wrap it up one more level.
So from the main you just call a function in a class which has the autowired class OuterBeanImpl

Comment: @Massimo : I tried that, and its not working

Comment: By "roll out", do you mean "rollback"? How do you check that the transaction is rollbacked? What's the stack trace of the exception you're catching?

Comment: @JBNizet: yes, I mean rollback. In this code first method in transaction is inserting records and second method is throwing an exception. In present scenario, as exception is thrown the record insertion must be rolled back. Isn't it?

Comment: It's strange, it's working fine for me, I'm using Oracle db, though...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have rollback when throwing exception at OuterBeanImpl? 
Enable logging and log spring transaction debug messages. That could help seeing what is going on.